# How to combine two objects of different types in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

Initially, I define

```
a = {};
b:any;
```

After some processing i get

```
a = {p:"ram", f:"sita"};

b = {"gita","mita"};
```

I tried to merge these two results. I tried

```
cart = [];

cart.push(this.a);
cart.push(this.b);
console.log(this.cart);
```

and get the result as below:

```
{p: "ram", f: "sita"}

{b: ["gita","mita"]}
```

I want the result like:

```
a ={p:"ram", f:"sita", b:"gita","mita"}
```

How can I achieve the above.

Comment: `{"3", "5"}` is not valid javascript, neither is `{b:"3", "5"}` so what are you actually wanting?

Comment: I'd really avoid both any and `{}`. I think building up objects gradually (by changing it over time) is a bit of an anti-pattern in Typescript. There's better ways to write it, just combine all the properties into the final object as the last step.

Comment: Please, don't mutate your variables. It is hard to debug and hard to type. Just my opinion

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted isn't valid TypeScript nor JavaScript, but I assume you meant something like this:

```
a      = { p: "1", f: "2" };
b      = [ "3", "5" ];
output = { p: "1", f: "2", b: [ "3", "5" ] };
```

In which case, you don't need to do anything special: TypeScript fully understands what `Object.assign` does:

```
interface AWithB {
    readonly a: { readonly p: string, readonly f: string };
    readonly b: readonly string[];
}

const a      = { p: "1", f: "2" };
const b      = [ "3", "5" ];
const output = Object.assign( {}, a, { b: b } );

function requiresAWithB( arg: AWithB ): void {
    console.log( arg );
}

requiresAWithB( output ); // <-- no error, because `output` matches `interface AWithB`.
```